# PyCharm chache taking too much space

Tags: pycharm

Currently, my PyCharm cache is taking 4.3 GB of space. I tried running `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart`, but even after restart it still takes same amount of space. I am on a Mac running macOS Catalina.

Comment: Do you use any symlinks in your projects? Maybe your projects contain some data folders, try to exclude them from indexing (Mark directory as Excluded), then invalidate caches again.

Comment: How do I find out which projects are linking data?